# CSV file restore in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Export MySql data in following command.

```
SELECT id,documentfile
FROM documentuploads
INTO OUTFILE '/home/home2/agri_doc.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**CSV file data**

```
"3","%PDF-1.7\
%����\
1 0 obj\
<<\
/Type /Catalog\
/Pages 2 0 R\
>>\"
```

I am currently using **mongodb shell version v3.6.3**. i want to import my csv file in mongo database, and I have created a collection **documentupload** where only two field **id, docs**. data is **latin1_swedish_ci** encoded. I tried following command.

```
mongorestore -d agrilicense2 -c documentupload  --type csv --file /home/shiva/home/agri_doc3.csv  --fields id, docs --headerline
```

Show output
**error parsing command line options: unknown option "type"** 
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you want to restore (.csv) file. As i am able to see in your statement you want to **import** the (.csv) file.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan my complete file CSV file path /home/shiva/home/agri_doc3.csv

Comment: I have been updated the answer with respect to import of (.csv) file.

Comment: If you want to import only the two fields (i.e., id,docs) then why not delete rest of the field from the (.csv) file . To avoid to write down more arguments in the mongo shell command.

Comment: As i understood you have been imported some MySQL data in (.csv) format and want to export in MongoDB. Right

Comment: If you want to import the **.csv** file in MongoDB then use the mongoimport inplace of mongoexport. The mongoimport tool imports content from an Extended JSON, CSV, or TSV export created by mongoexport, or potentially, another third-party export tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the (.csv) file through the following commands

```
mongoimport -d databaseName -c collectionName --type csv --file locationsOftheCSVFile.csv --headerline
```

**For example** here I have created the database name **test** and collection name **StackExchange** and going to import the **LocarionReq.csv** file.

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.createCollection("StackExchange");
{ "ok" : 1 }
> show collections
StackExchange

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongoimport -d test -c StackExchange --type csv --file C:\test\LocationReq.csv --headerline
2019-04-11T10:58:53.147+0300    connected to: localhost
2019-04-11T10:58:53.263+0300    imported 1000 documents
```

Now you can check the total document records through the mongo shell command

```
>db.StackExchange.find().count();
 1000
```

If you want to find the document records through mongo shell then run the command such as

```
> db.StackExchange.find().pretty(); -- an easy-to-read attractive format.

Or

> db.StackExchange.find();
```

> **Note :** Run `mongoimport` or `mongoexport` from the system command line, not the mongo shell.

For your further ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Comment: error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed

Comment: @shivaManhar, did you try this >mongoimport -d agrilicense2 -c documentupload  --type csv --file /home/shiva/home/agri_doc3.csv  --headerline . I mean to say that after the location file of **.csv** only write down the **--headerline**.

Comment: yes -- file /home/shiva/home/agri_doc.csv --headerline output Failed: line 111, column 14: extraneous " in field

Comment: @ShivaManhar In your **agri_doc.csv** file, check the value present in row number 111 and column number 14 for any special characters. This link can help you with correcting this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573851/how-to-import-data-containing-double-quotes-into-mongodb-using-mongoimport

Answer (score 1):

Before going to answer i want to say thanks Md Haidar Ali Khan,  Mani and all.
1. First change MySQL Export(dump) query. **documentfile** not is base64 format so before export change **documentfile** ot base65 through **TO_BASE64** method.

```
SELECT id,TO_BASE64(documentfile)
FROM documentuploads
INTO OUTFILE 'agri_doc64.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**mongoimport command**

```
mongoimport --db agrilicense2 --collection documentupload  --type csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields "id.int32(),documentfile.binary(base64)" --file /home/shiva/home/agri_doc64.csv
```

I hope this code help other and save lot of time.